# two `mergeMap` aren't lazy

Tags: javascript, rxjs

```
import { of, mergeMap, concatAll, toArray, take } from 'rxjs'

const duplicateValue = log => value => {
  console.log(log, value)
  return Promise.resolve([value, value]);
}

of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10).pipe(
  mergeMap(duplicateValue('mapping a'), 1),
  concatAll(),
  mergeMap(duplicateValue('mapping b'), 1),
  concatAll(),
  take(3),
  toArray(),
)
  .subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

output:

```
mapping a
1
mapping b
1
mapping a
2
mapping b
1
mapping a
3
[1, 1, 1]
```

only 3 values are taken eventually so I would like it to run the mappers as little as possible, if it were truely lazy evaluation then i would expect the first mapper to run once, producing 2 values, then the second mapper to run twice, producing 4 values

the `1` parameter to mergeMap should do something of this sort but does not really

i got a bit close using `concatMap` but still not perfect

i think it is something subtle about the interoperation of promises and rxjs

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons why the `mergeMap` in your example may not be lazy.

1. `Promise.resolve` is already eagerly evaluated, so the `duplicateValue` function will always return a resolved promise before the `mergeMap` even runs.
2. The `concatAll` operator itself is not lazy. It immediately subscribes to the inner observables and begins emitting values. So even if the `mergeMap` were lazy, the `concatAll` will still eagerly consume all the values.
3. The `take` operator also eagerly subscribes to the source observable and begins emitting values. So even if the `mergeMap` and `concatAll` were lazy, the `take` will prevent them from being lazily evaluated.

In order to have lazy evaluation, you would need to use operators like `defer` or `Observable.create` to defer the execution until the subscription happens. Additionally, you would have to avoid `Promise.resolve` and instead use `defer` or `Observable.fromPromise` to create a lazy promise.